# How to namespace coffeescript in a Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

In my Rails project, in which I am using Coffeescript, I want to be able to do something like this in a view:

```
f.text_area :content, :size => "77x4", :oninput => 'Helpers.expandTextarea(300)'
```

This would call a coffeescript function that would expand the textarea when required. My problem is that I can't seem to properly namespace the coffeescript to get this to work. I tried to do it like this

```
# site.js.coffee
Helpers =
  expandTextarea: ->
    alert "function found!"
```

This doesn't work. Trying to call `Helpers` in the browser console will throw an `undefined` error. My question is this:

**What code would I use in site.js.coffee to achieve the namespacing I want?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could manually put `Helpers` into the global namespace:

```
window.Helpers =
  expandTextarea: ->
    alert "function found!"
```

Then you should be able to say `Helpers.expandTextarea(300)` anywhere you want. Assuming, of course, that `site.js.coffee` is included on every page.

CoffeeScript files are wrapped in functions by default:

```
(function() { /* compiled CoffeeScript goes here */ })();
```

to avoid polluting the global namespace. You can supply options to the CoffeeScript compiler to not wrap like this but you're better off explicitly putting global things into `window`.